# Ajax Sourced DataTable inside jquery Tab returns all rows as selected

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable, datatables

I am fairly new to DataTables and still finding my feet. I have come across an issue with which I require assistance. I have a page with 2 jquery tabs. Inside each tab, exist an ajax sourced DataTable.

The Issue:
When I do a count to determine the number of selected rows, DataTables always returns all rows in dataset as selected.

Please see the test case at : [Test Case](http://live.datatables.net/kilaneke/1/edit) In the 2nd Tab "VENDORS" , click the "ADD VENDOR" button. This will log a count of the number of selected rows to the console.

As you can see it shows all 57 rows as selected.

Kindly advise a solution on how to solve this issue or any suitable workaround.

Regards,

Comment: Seems you don't have a select check box in the table, That's why it returns all of the rows.columnDefs': [
         {
            'targets': 0,
            'checkboxes': {
            'selectRow': true
            }

Comment: Sorry..u did not add the checkbox column to the example. The live version had the select (checkbox) option enabled..still the same issue

Comment: Yes, your live version has select. But check your output. Does it give checkbox in your html output. Also inspect your html output that does not have any checkbox. My question is, the way you created checkbox is it correct or not?

Comment: What I have noticed so far is that  'table1.rows({ selected: true }).every(function(index){'  is evaluating every row. I think due to the tab being in a delegated method, it cannot evaluate the condition as yet

Comment: @TharsanSivakumar I have tracked down he issue. plz have a look if it is within area of expertise http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39859251/evaluating-functions-inside-jquery-tabs

Answer (score 0):

For those whom this may be of assistance; instead of(which works fine outside jquery tabs):

```
table.rows({ selected: true }).every(function(index){
                // Get and store row ID
                data.push(this.data()[0]);
                $count++;
                });
```

Use the following method;

```
 table.rows('.selected').every(function(index){
                    // Get and store row ID
                    data.push(this.data()[0]);
                    $count++;
                });
```

The developers of the plugin may provide an insight as to why the second method works inside tabs